# C# Get total inside area of scrollable panel

Tags: c#, width, panel, area

Should be a nice easy one for someone...

I have a panel which I am dynamically adding child controls to, to the point where scroll bars will appear when any of them are placed outside of the visible area.

I need to know the total size of this area. i.e. how wide the scrollable area is?

I could get the furthest placed control and use its left + width properties, but there must be a cleaner way?

Edit: Hopefully this illustrates what I need (Scrollable area width).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarArrowWidth
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.verticalscrollbarwidth.aspx

Comment: I'm using .Net 3.5 I should mention. Not really any examples on that page that suggests they will do what I need?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand the question, try with AutoScrollMargin property.

Comment: Thanks, but that value appears to always be 0.

Comment: No i already tried that, its always the same as the width of the panel.

Comment: Yes winforms, although all of a sudden that value started changing. So it is DisplayRectangle! Sorry about that...